# How do I round a positive float up the next integer?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I need to round a positive float upwards to the nearest integer.

```
examples;

1.0 rounds up to 1    
2.1 rounds up to 3
3.5 rounds up to 4
4.9 rounds up to 5
```

i.e. always round up.

Comment: FWIW, rounding upwards, and nearest are incompatible. You mean simply to round up.

Comment: What should -4.4 round to? -5 or -4?

Comment: See http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/System.Math.Ceil

Comment: @AustinFrench Why not? Looks like rounding to me. Round to nearest is not the only way to round. You can round to nearest multiple of 10, round to 2dp, round up, round down, round towards zero, round away from zero. Lots of different forms of rounding exist.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan OK, yes technically... It just seems "rounding" is such a generic and useless term when it is used in place of IMO more accurate phrases. For example 1 doesn't actually *round* anywhere. Maybe its just me.

Comment: @AustinFrench, thats because `1` is integer already. But suppose the rounding to 10¹ and here you are.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use the [`Ceil`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Math.Ceil) function from the `Math` unit. From the documentation:

> Rounds variables up toward positive infinity.
>
> Call Ceil (as in ceiling) to obtain the lowest integer greater than or
>   equal to X. The absolute value of X must be less than MaxInt. For
>   example:
>
> - Ceil(-2.8) = -2
> - Ceil(2.8) = 3
> - Ceil(-1.0) = -1

---

I cannot tell whether or not the behaviour of `Ceil` meets your expectations for negative input values, because you did not specify what to do there. However, if `Ceil` does not meet your expectations, it is easy enough to write a function to meet your needs, by combining `Abs()` and `Ceil()`

Comment: That's exactly what I want, but is System.Math available on win32 (or .net only)?

Comment: On D2010, it is the `Math` unit. On DXE2 or later, with namespaces it is `System.Math`.

Answer (score -3):

```
FindField('QTY').ASFLOAT := TRUNC(FindField('QTY').ASFLOAT) + 1
```

Works Fine

Comment: Not so good on negative numbers and whole positive numbers.

Comment: The question is simply mathematical - the database gymnastics are irrelevant and, as LU RD said, don't return the correct results required by the OP.